# React Native: trucate text if bigger than width percentage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

in react native having a Text component with a given width in percentages how can I trucate that text with ellipsis if the resulting text is bigger than the given width?

```
<Text style={{width:'50%'}}>{ dynamic.text }</Text>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it with these two properties

```
      <Text
        numberOfLines={1}
        ellipsizeMode="tail"
        style={{ width: '40%' }}>
        Long text that will be truncated if it exceeds the container
      </Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass [numberOfLines](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#numberoflines) prop.

This is used to truncate the text. You can use this prop with another prop called [ellipsizeMode](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#ellipsizemode) to define how text will be truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the property `numberOfLines`, that can be passed to the `<Text>` and then just update the styling.

```js
<View style={styles.container}>
<Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.text}>{dynamic.text}</Text>
</View>

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: 10
  },

  text: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '50%'
  }
});
```